# Converting an ARGB32 (py)cairo surface to a PIL(low) image - inverse colors?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, cairo, pycairo

I *think* am doing some trivial standard task: I am converting a (py)`cairo` surface to a `PIL`(low) image. The original `cairo` surface uses `ARGB` mode. The target `PIL` image uses `RGBA`, i.e. I want to maintain all colors and the alpha channel. However, things get really bizarre in the conversion: It appears that `cairo` stores its data internally as `BGRA`, so I actually need to swap the color channels during the conversion, see here:

```py
import cairo

import gi
gi.require_version('Rsvg', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Rsvg

from PIL import Image

w, h = 600, 600
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h,)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

ctx.set_source_rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) # explicitly draw white background
ctx.rectangle(0, 0, w, h)
ctx.fill()

# tested with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pleiszenburg/abgleich/v0.0.7/src/abgleich/share/icon.svg
layout = Rsvg.Handle.new_from_file('icon.svg')
layout.render_cairo(ctx)

# EXPORT TEST #1: cairo
surface.write_to_png('export_cairo.png') # ok, looks as expected

pil = Image.frombuffer(mode = 'RGBA', size = (w, h), data = surface.get_data(),)

b, g, r, a = pil.split() # Color swap, part 1: Splitting the channels
pil = Image.merge('RGBA', (r, g, b, a)) # Color swap, part 2: Rearranging the channels

# EXPORT TEST #2: PIL
pil.save('export_pil.png') # ok, looks as expected IF COLORS ARE REARRANGED AS ABOVE
```

The above test uses `rsvg`, but it can also be reproduced by simply drawing a few colorful lines with `cairo`.

Am I terribly misunderstanding something or is this actually the right way to do it?

Comment: What is `gi` package please?

Comment: Your last line says *"looks ok if colours are rearranged"*. How do you rearrange them please - what command?

Comment: @MarkSetchell See the lines commented with "color swap" part 1 and 2. This is where I rearrange / swap them. `gi.version_info` says `(3, 36, 1)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. It means *"if rearranged as above"*, not *"if rearranged afterwards"*. I took it for granted they had been rearranged according to the code I'd just read.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, yes this was confusing. I just clarified it.

Comment: What is the full name of `gi` package please? I don't see it in `pip` or `pypi`.

Comment: It's [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/). Actually, `gi` is completely irrelevant for this question. You can reproduce this behavior with `cairo` and a few lines drawn directly with `cairo` alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the cairo documentation (https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t):

> CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32
>
> each pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with alpha in the upper 8 bits, then red, then green, then blue. The 32-bit quantities are stored native-endian. Pre-multiplied alpha is used. (That is, 50% transparent red is 0x80800000, not 0x80ff0000.) (Since 1.0)

So, on little endian, this is actually what PIL calls BGRA, I think.

Not directly related to your question, but this is Pre-multiplied alpha.

According to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes, the only mode with premultiplied alpha is `'RGBa'`.

> or is this actually the right way to do it?

No idea what "right" means. However, my comment would be: there must be some way to do this without going through an intermediate image.

Since Pillow does not support cairo's image mode, perhaps you can instead use something numpy-y to do the conversion. For example, pycairo's test suite contains the following: https://github.com/dalembertian/pycairo/blob/22d29e0820d0dcbe070a6eb6f8f302e8c41b71a7/test/isurface_get_data.py#L37-L42

```
buf = surface.get_data()
a = numpy.ndarray (shape=(w,h,4), dtype=numpy.uint8, buffer=buf)

# draw a vertical line
a[:,40,0] = 255  # byte 0 is blue on little-endian systems
a[:,40,1] = 0
a[:,40,2] = 0
```

So, to convert from (in Pillow-speak) BGRa to RGBa, you could do something like this to swap the red and blue channels (where `a` is a buffer similar to the above):

```
(a[:,:,0], a[:,:,2]) = (a[:,:,2], a[:,:,0])
```

If this is really better than your approach of going through an intermediate `Image`... well, I do not know. You have to judge what is the best approach to do this. At least you should now be able to explain why it is necessary (there is no common image format supported by both cairo and PIL)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "numpy-y" concept is about as slow as the intermediate `Image` - I tested it. Probably a similar number of memcopies. The "Pre-multiplied alpha" bit made me think whether I actually also need to correct the color values when converting from cairo to PIL (or whether I must go through an another RGBa intermediate PIL image before going to an RGBA PIL image) ... (?)